# javascript async with multiple await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js

I have three api request to work asynchronous, but the second request is working before the first request is completed. How do I get the second api request to start after completing the first request and then third after the second?

```
async doSave(event)
{
  await this.server.post('/insertRecord',{name:'joe'});

            //have to work after completion of above request

  await this.server.post('/changeCountry',{countryName:'US'});

          //have to work after completion of above request

  await this.server.post('/satge',{stage:'fifth'});
}
```

Comment: Well, just like you wrote it. Does it work?

Comment: No its not working

Comment: if your app breaks because of the order of requests, your doing it wrong.

Comment: What kind of API / Object is `this.server`?

Answer (score 3):

If your second request starts before your first request, it means that the Promise returned by `this.server.post` resolves before the request is complete. Alternatively, it does not return a Promise at all in which case it starts your asynchronous request, and then runs the next line in this function after `this.server.post` returns.

Answer (score 1):

The server should return a promise, in that case await will wait for it to resolve. In the code below I did a mock of the server to test the whole code. It will do the work synchonously.

```js
const server = {
  post: function(url, data) {
    const time = 300 + Math.random() * 1500;
    console.log("Posting at " + url + " ... (" + Math.round(time) + "ms)");
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), time)
    );
  }
};

async function doSave(event) {
  await server.post('/insertRecord', {
    name: 'joe'
  });

  //have to work after completion of above request
  console.log('doing Work after InsertRecord');
  await server.post('/changeCountry', {
    countryName: 'US'
  });

  //have to work after completion of above request
  console.log('doing Work after changeCountry');
  await server.post('/satge', {
    stage: 'fifth'
  });
}
doSave();
```

Output:

```
Posting at /insertRecord ... (1306ms)
doing Work after InsertRecord
Posting at /changeCountry ... (1752ms)
doing Work after changeCountry
Posting at /satge ... (1616ms)
```

Check [this link for more information about await, async, promises](https://javascript.info/async)

Answer (score 0):

ideally `this.server` - should return [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (axios for eg returns promises), but if it does not than you can use `Promises` instead of `Async/await` and chain your requests one after another.