# My Second API is running before first getting executed in React js, typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I am running two API's inside async function in react JS. Sometimes It is working fine but sometimes second API is running before first is finished.
Here is my code -

```
Interface A {
    onSaveClick: (myData: DataInfo, hasDone: boolean) => void;
}
const onSaveClick =  async (myData: DataInfo, hasDone: boolean):Promise<void> => {
    await saveData(myData, hasDone); // first API
    await getData("A", "B", "C"); // second API
};
```

Sometimes it works fine but sometimes not. I don't want to use setTimeout. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426926/javascript-async-with-multiple-await) answer your question?

Comment: Nobody could answer your question without knowing how `saveData` and `getData` are defined. Also, this question doesn't appear to be related to [tag:reactjs].

Comment: need more information. share your saveDAta and getData code